# Output two-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Ok, I'm still struggling with my arrays... I have created a two-dimensional array and saved into a session to get results on another page: $_SESSION['myARRAY']

```
print_r($_SESSION['myARRAY']);

// will output:
Array ( [Car] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 9 [2] => 0 ) 
        [Truck] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 10 [2] => 0 ) 
        [Bus] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 [2] => 2 ))
```

Now I need to output the data into the following format:

```
$xls->addRow(Array("Car",1,9,0));
$xls->addRow(Array("Truck",2,10,0));
$xls->addRow(Array("Bus",1,8,2));
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['myARRAY'] AS $key => $value) {

    $arr[$key] = $key;

    foreach($value AS $k => $v) {
        $arr[$key] = $v;
    }

    $xls->addRow($arr[$key]);
}
```

but it did not really work. I think I'm close but not quite there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$value` is already an array. Now you only need to prepend the `$key` to it. You could use [**`array_unshift`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
foreach($_SESSION['myARRAY'] AS $key => $value) {
    array_unshift($value, $key);
    $xls->addRow($value);
}
```

Of course if you do this more than once, you should consider storing the consolidated array.

Comment: `$value` already is a copy since it isn't a reference. I don't  see the point of making the second copy, especially if the loop only does that.

Comment: @konforce: True, forgot about that... I got a bit confused because `array_unshift` works in-place... changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `array_unshift` as it seems like a more appropriate way to solve this problem, but you could also do it like:

```
foreach($_SESSION['myARRAY'] AS $key => $value) {
    $xls->addRow(array_merge(array($key), $value));
}
```